# Compare daily counts of orders from current month vs daily count from last moth

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to compare the difference between this month daily orders count vs last month daily orders count and group them by day using postgresql sql query.

Example:

`1st of nov count - 1st of oct count`

Comment: Well, a good way to start such a query is with `SELECT`.

Comment: @Riv I know how to get the daily orders grouped by day for current and last month. My issue is how to compare each day count with the equivalent of past month and im not sure how. Im guessing a self join or something might help but im not sure.

Comment: @GordonLinoff isn't it always :)

Comment: update your question and show your table schema  .. (and eventually your test query)

Answer (score 0):

Simply calculate date in previous month and join on that

```
create table sales (
   d DATE
  ,orederCount INT 
);

INSERT INTO sales(d, orederCount) VALUES  ('2016-11-01',12),('2016-10-01',10),('2016-09-01',10)
                                         ,('2016-11-02',13),('2016-10-02',14),('2016-09-02',5);   



with data as (select d,(d-INTERVAL '1 month')::DATE as p,orederCount from sales)
select current.d,current.orederCount - COALESCE(prev.orederCount,0) as diff 
from data as current 
LEFT JOIN data as prev ON current.p = prev.d
;
```

Result:

```
2016-09-01,10
2016-09-02,5
2016-10-01,0
2016-10-02,9
2016-11-01,2
2016-11-02,-1
```